# How to delete or remove list key redis with .net core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have issue delete bulk key with redis. Numbers of records about 500k key, below code each key:

```
 //delete each key
 var getKeys = redis.GetServer("27.71.234.124", 7778).Keys(0, "item").ToArray();
 await db.KeyDeleteAsync(getKeys);
```

How to way delete/remove numbers bulk recordsin redis ?

Comment: Do you want to delete all the keys in redis at once? Try to use the FlushDatabaseAsync or FlushAllDatabasesAsync method to delete all keys in the Redis database, refer to this article:https://www.thecodebuzz.com/delete-keys-all-keys-redis-cache-cluster-net-csharp-net-core/

Answer (score 1):

Please try like:

```
        IAsyncEnumerable<RedisKey> keys = redis.GetServer("27.71.234.124", 7778).KeysAsync(0, "pattern", 1000);

        await foreach(RedisKey key in keys)
        {
            await db.KeyDeleteAsync(key);
        }
```

Here pageSize = 1000 -- can change this based on your server settings